# Add the elements of an initializer list

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I'm trying to write a generic function that takes an initializer-list as argument, adds the elements, and then returns that number. If the list is empty then it should return 0. The code looks correct to me, but whenever I run it, it returns 4,199,041 instead of 10 from the {1, 2, 3, 4} I input. I changed the function to print out the elements as opposed to adding them and that works out fine, it outputs 1234, so I have no idea what the issue is. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename T>
//add elements of initializer list
T total(initializer_list<T> & elements)
{
    T tmp;
    if(elements.size() != 0)
    {
        for(auto itr = elements.begin(); itr != elements.end(); ++itr)
        {
            tmp += *itr;
            return tmp;
        }
    }else
        return 0;
}

int main()
{
    initializer_list<int> num({1, 2, 3, 4});
    cout << total(num);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `tmp` is uninitialized and the `return tmp;` is misplaced.

Comment: Oh wow, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you. I have no idea why I had the return in the for loop.

Answer (score 3):

You may consider std::accumulate:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename T>
//add elements of initializer list
T total(std::initializer_list<T> & elements)
{
    // Note: Using 0 will decay the result to an integer, hence the T{} for zero.
    return std::accumulate(elements.begin(), elements.end(), T{});

    // Fixing the original code (where tmp is uninitialized 
    // and the return tmp; is misplaced):
    // T tmp = 0;
    // for(auto itr = elements.begin(); itr != elements.end(); ++itr)
    //  tmp += *itr;
    // return tmp;
}

int main()
{
    std::initializer_list<int> num({1, 2, 3, 4});
    std::cout << total(num) << '\n';
}
```